# How can I use e.CommandName in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set `OnItemCommand` in `Repeater` but in `Page_Load` I need e.CommandName.

How can access `e.CommandName` Repeater in Page_Load?

Comment: why do you need to access e.commandName in Page_Load?

Comment: because for query in db i need ID and this qurey must be excute on page_load!now i need e.commandName for ID

Comment: I have never really needed to retrieve data during post back in Page_Load. If you do retrieve data there and use it for binding, you will find that all other events will never get kicked off anymore due to the additional binding pre event handling. Your binding should happen when !IsPostback and if you need to handle any event, do that in your specified EventHandler for OnItemCommand (or any other event for your web controls inside the repeater like a LinkButton.OnClick)

Answer (score 0):

i found solution!
use Javascript

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format(" test(\"{0}\")", Eval("ID")) 

<asp:HiddenField ID="jk" runat="server" />


    <script>
        function test(sender) {
            document.getElementById("<%=jk.ClientID%>").value = sender;
        }
    </script>
```

when click on item Repeter call method javascript and then call page_load
that's it!